# What drove the inventors of float mechanism?

Tags: css

Now in the days of flexbox and grid, floats seem to be very unintuitive way of thinking about styling page layout (at least for me). My question is - what is the crazy logic behind floats?

Comment: This isn't really a question for stackoverflow, should be moved to meta. I imagine floats were inspired by newspaper layouts. Might seem crazy now when you've got flex box but it worked pretty well.

Comment: Floats are not supposed to be used for layout, that was just a necessary hack because there was nothing really good for layout

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a specific coding problem and is open ended

Comment: @AlanSutherland No, this question should not be moved to meta, as it is not about Stack Overflow, but about CSS `float`.

Answer (score 2):

If you find floats non-intuitive, it's because you're trying to use them for the wrong thing. See this [diagram from the CSS 2.2 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#propdef-float).

[image: Floated element surrounded by two paragraphs]

Try replicating that with flexbox or grid layouts.